# I got error and i can't fix.. SQL ERROR in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, ajax

I got error and i can't fix..

```
response error:
Database query failedYou have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '' as Loreta Punzalan'}, 
gender  = {'Female'}, dob = {'01/23/20' at line 2
```

JS AJAX

```
$("button.update_btn").click(function(event){
        //alert("test");
        var clickedEditid = this.id.split('-');
        var dbId = clickedEditid[1];
        var mydata = '&recordToBeUpdated='+ dbId;
        var mydatas = $('#instructorUps').serialize();
            var datas = mydatas+mydata;
        //alert(datas);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/includes/response_instructor_update.php?>",
            dataType:"text",
            data: datas,
            success: function(response){
                alert(response);
            // $('#ins_'+dbId).fadeIn();
                //$('#instructorModal').append(response);
                location.reload();
                },
            error:function(xhr, ajaxOption, thrownError){
                alert(thrownError);
                }

            });
        });
```

Response_instructor_update.php

```
<?php
// Response for AJAX

require_once("connection.php");
require_once("functions.php");
if(isset($_POST['fullnameup'])){

        $idupdate     =   mysql_prep($_POST["recordToBeUpdated"]);
        $fullname     =   mysql_prep($_POST["fullnameup"]);
        $username     =   mysql_prep($_POST["usernameup"]);
        $gender       =   mysql_prep($_POST["genderup"]);
        $dob          =   mysql_prep($_POST["dobup"]);
        $nationality  =   mysql_prep($_POST["nationalityup"]);
        $mobile       =   mysql_prep($_POST["mobileup"]);
        $emailadd     =   mysql_prep($_POST["emailaddup"]);
        $address      =   mysql_prep($_POST["addressup"]);
        $zipcode      =   mysql_prep($_POST["zipcodeup"]);
$query  = "UPDATE instructor SET    
            instructor    = {'$fullname'},
            gender        = {'$gender'},
            dob           = {'$dob'},
            nationality   = {'$nationality'},
            mobile       = {$mobile},
            emailadd     = {'$emailadd'},
            address      = {'$address'},
            zipcode      = {$zipcode},
            username     = {'$username'}
            WHERE instructorid= {$idupdate}";   
    $updatedInstructor = mysql_query($query,$connection);
    confirm_query($updatedInstructor);

    if (mysql_affected_rows() == 1){

        echo "TRUE";
        mysql_close($connection);
        }else{
            die("Database query failed". mysql_error());

            } 
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: What are your intentions with the `{}` encapsulation? As it's likely they're wrong.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to use `{}` when interpolating then they need to be directly next to the variable (i.e. `{$fullname}`. Putting the curly braces outside the single quotes, `{'$fullname'}`, will not work; the braces will simply be part of the query, which gives you a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right idea. However, you have a slight syntax issue.

I believe your variables are not evaluating to strings, and MySQL is expecting strings. Try the following instead:

```
$query  = "UPDATE instructor SET    
        instructor    = '{$fullname}',
        gender        = '{$gender}',
        dob           = '{$dob}',
        nationality   = '{$nationality}',
        mobile       = {$mobile},
        emailadd     = '{$emailadd}',
        address      = '{$address}',
        zipcode      = {$zipcode},
        username     = '{$username}',
        WHERE instructorid= {$idupdate}";
```

Note that the single quotes (') are OUTSIDE of the curly brackets ({}). You must add the quotes anywhere that MySQL expects strings (column type is text/varchar/etc..).

## - Update -

As sverri said, they actually are being treated as strings. The issue here is that php's interpolation has minor variations: you may either use `{$variable}` OR simply `$variable` inside double quoted (") strings. In the case of your post, you had `{'$variable'}` which was interpolating using the `$variable` method, and just treating the curly brackets as part of the string, when you had the intention of PHP replacing them.

Comment: And so it's said: phone numbers and zip codes are *not numbers*.  They're strings that just happen to be made of digits.  Get in the habit of treating them as such, and it'll make your life easier later.

Comment: What @cHao means is that you will find best practice in data capturing would merit that you treat mobile & zipcode as strings. For example, imagine: `(333)333-4444`. Or 5+4 digit zip codes: `55555-4444` - the parenthesis/dashes require a string compatible data type. Or even worse; your numbers start with 0's and, hence, the leading 0's are dropped.

Comment: The variables *are* being evaluated as strings. The problem is that the curly braces are being evaluated as strings as well, unless they wrap the variables directly.

Comment: It Does! @kerns Thank you!! thank for the  other comments.. it helps.. Cheers

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen: I'm specifically looking at the lack of quotes around the values for `mobile` and `zipcode` in the SQL.  Without them, MySQL's going to consider those values to be numbers -- which is going to break if the value has a non-digit in it.  (That it's being done at all, though, hints to me that the fields are actually declared as numbers.  Which is wrongheaded in itself.)